# complex hierarchy updates based on form input

Tags: grails

I am trying to understand the best way to work with complex hierarchies of objects that i manipulate based on data on forms in Grails.

I cannot use the command object as my form is dynamic (users can add any number of records). I am told we should parse the params in controller and let services do the transaction activities on the domain objects and thus reduce coupling. Sometimes this doesn't seem straightforward.

I have a few lists of child domain objects in a base domain object that is being 'updated' which means the list could have grown or reduced, meaning some domain tuples will need to be added/removed, how do i pass that information from controller to service without making a function with 8 parameters? If anyone has any strategies you've used, please share. I am sure this is not uncommon but I haven't seen any discussions on such a question.

e.g.

```
class DomainA {
    List<DomainB> bList
    List<DomainC> cList
    DomainD domD
}

class DomainD {
    List<DomainE> elist
}
```

Comment: Considering your example. Why don´t you save Domain D First as a first Step. Then you could save DomainA, as you will need it´s ID to work. After  domainAInstance is saved you will be able to create little ajax forms that add instances to bList, clist, etc. By using ajax the fact that you are saving every Time will become transparent to the user. It might also save you and them the pain of having to recreate everything if something fails, or constant rollbacks in your transactions.

Comment: A bean. You can make it bendable to actual domain class as well as validatable if required. Most importantly it can bind the params which can be registered List objects straight from controller to service. If issues in service fail it and pass bean back to view from controller. Take a look at some of my plugins I used bean to bind prams from controller to service

Answer (score 0):

How about relying on ajax. You might save classD and then class A, or use a command object to save both. Then with the Id´s of these two classes you might add everything else you need using ajax.

[image]